Question regarding prove that $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n }$ does not converge
I have seen proofs that show that $\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n}$, (where $X_i$ are standard normal distributed and independent) does not converge. They mostly use Kolmogorov's 0-1 law and the CLT. (See Showing $\limsup \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$)
What they did was using Fatou's lemma to conclude
$\newcommand{\>}{\color{red}{\boldsymbol >}}$
$$ \mathbb{P} \left(\limsup \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n} \> x\right) \ge \limsup  \mathbb{P} \left(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n} \> x\right) = \mathbb{P} \big(N(0,1) \> x\big) > 0, $$
leading to $\limsup \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n } = \infty$.
However, I do not see why we cannot conclude
$\newcommand{\<}{\color{red}{\boldsymbol <}}$
$$ \mathbb{P} \left(\limsup \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n} \< x\right) \ge \limsup  \mathbb{P} \left(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n} \< x\right) = \mathbb{P} \big(N(0,1) \< x\big) > 0, $$
leading to $\limsup \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n} = -\infty$.
It must be something obvious I am missing. I would appreciate some help.

What does $(n)$ stand for?

@geetha290krm that is a Latex issue I am having. It should just be $sqrt(n)$

Use just \sqrt n with no brackets.

Thank you very much!

Leading to $limsup \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n } = \infty$ is wrong in the first proof and Leading to $limsup \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n } =- \infty$ is wrong in the second proof. Why can't $limsup \frac{X_1+...+X_n}{\sqrt n }$ itself be $N(0,1)$?

The first proof is not wrong. $\lim\sup \frac{X_{1}+...+X_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ is $+\infty$ and cannot be normally distributed. A simple application of the Law of iterated logarithm says so. What can be said is that the op should have elaborated that $P(\lim\sup S_{n}/\sqrt{n}>x)=1$ (By 0-1 law) for each $x$ and hence $\lim\sup S_{n}/\sqrt{n}=+\infty$ almost surely. @geetha290krm

@Mr.GandalfSauron Such missing details make the proof wrong. I did not say that the proof cannot be corrected.

@geetha290krm Agreed. But the op did mention Kolmogorov's Zero-One law and CLT and did link an answer. It is natural to expect that the op simply omitted further details instead of concluding in an erroneous way. It is for those reasons that I would refrain from using the word "wrong" here.

I updated the question with some more MathJax advice. For some reason the display equations were not overfull in the preview, but they are now I've published.

Denote $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ .
The problem is that $\{\lim\sup \frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}<x\}\neq \lim\sup\{\frac{S_{n}}{n}<x\}$
Where $\lim\sup A_{n}=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n} A_{k}$ .
If $\omega \in \lim\sup\{\frac{S_{n}}{n}<x\}$ this means that $\frac{S_{n}(\omega)}{\sqrt{n}}<x$ for infinitely many $n$. This does not mean that $\lim\sup \frac{S_{n}(\omega)}{\sqrt{n}}<x$ . Take a real sequence $x_{n}$ defined by $x_{2n}=-n$ and $x_{2n-1}=0$
Then, even though $x_{n}<-100$ for infinitely many $n$, you still have $\lim\sup x_{n}=0$ and not $<-100$
Let's go through the proof once.
Written in terms of indicators, when you are applying Fatou's lemma, you are applying to the sequence $\mathbf{1}_{A_{n}}$ where $A_{n}=\{S_{n}/{\sqrt{n}}<x\}$. And for any sequence of sets $B_{n}$, you always have $\lim\sup\mathbf{1}_{B_{n}}=\mathbf{1}_{\lim\sup B_{n}}$.
Now following the steps, you'll have
\begin{align}P(\lim\sup A_{n})&=E(\mathbf{1}_{\lim\sup A_{n}})\\\\&=E(\lim\sup \mathbf{1}_{A_{n}})\\\\&\stackrel{Fatou}{\geq} \lim\sup E(\mathbf{1}_{A_{n}})\\\\&=\lim\sup P(A_{n})\\\\&\stackrel{CLT}{=}P(N(0,1)<x) >0 \end{align}
Which allows you to conclude $P(\lim\sup A_{n})=1$ using Kolmogorov's Zero One law.  But, this does not tell you anything about $\{\lim\sup \frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}<x\}$ or it's probability as it does not equal $\lim\sup A_{n}$.
Do note that we have shown $P(\lim\sup A_{n})=1$. This means that $S_{n}/\sqrt{n}<x$ for infinitely many $n$ almost surely. This means that $\lim\inf S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\leq x$ almost surely. As this holds for all $x<0$, you have $\lim\inf S_{n}/\sqrt{n}=-\infty$ almost surely.
i.e. you get that $\lim\sup A_{n}\subseteq\{\lim\inf S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\leq x\}$ and since $P(\lim\sup A_{n})=1$, you have $P(\{\lim\inf S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\leq x\})=1$.


On the other hand, if $B_{n}=\{\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\geq x\}$, then repeating the same argument yields you that $P(\lim\sup B_{n})=1$ as $\lim\sup B_{n}$ is a Tail measurable event.
But this time, you do have that $\lim\sup B_{n}=\{\lim\sup \frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\geq x\}$. This is simply due to the fact that for $\omega \in \lim\sup B_{n}$, you have that $\frac{S_{n}(\omega)}{\sqrt{n}}\geq x$ for infinitely many $n$.
Thus, you'll be able to collect those $n$ and form a subsequence $n_{k}$ such that $S_{n_{k}}/\sqrt{n_{k}}\geq x$ for each $k$ and hence
$$\lim\sup S_{n}(\omega)/\sqrt{n}\geq \lim\sup S_{n_{k}}(\omega)/\sqrt{n_{k}}\geq \lim\inf S_{n_{k}}(\omega)/\sqrt{n_{k}}\geq  x$$

Thank you for the detailed and well written explanation!

@user007 Glad I could help.
